Azure PostgreSQL- Flexible Server PostgreSQL Anonymizer (ANON) Extension: change schema that should be masked
I am trying to get the ANON extension working on Azure PostgreSQL- Flexible Server  using a different schema to the public.
According to documentation this can be achieved by using
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET anon.sourceschema TO 'myschema';

Executing this I get
[42501] ERROR: permission denied to set parameter "anon.sourceschema"

By looking at the code in https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer I figured out, that this properties is stored in the postgres current_settings:
select quote_ident(pg_catalog.current_setting('anon.sourceschema'));

returns 'public'
I also directly tried to
SELECT set_config('anon.sourceschema', 'myschema', false);

which gives the same error as above.
The error indicates that I do not have sufficient permissions; So my question is, what permission do I need and how can I grant them to my user?
Microsoft does not give access to a superuser that should be able to achieve this.
Also open to have this done via azure-cli / Terraform.
I am using Azure PostgreSQL- Flexible Server v15.7, with anon extension version 1.3.2 installed.

Have you tried with extensions of postgresql server in azure portal?

I followed this guide: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/ModernizationBestPracticesBlog/implementing-oracle-data-masking-capabilities-in-azure-postgresql--flexible-serv/4255450
I have slight changes to try to use my schema; and I have tried a lot of things (not a database export though)
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS anon schema myschema;
ALTER ROLE masked_user SET search_path TO mask, myschema
Neither helped

It may be a limitation to mask schema in azure database PostgreSQL server.

I was able to set the schema for the anonymization extension with this command:
SET anon.sourceschema TO 'myschema';

Verify the result with:
SHOW anon.sourceschema;

I found it accidentally, and the documentation does not mention it. This was validated with the anon 1.6.3 and Azure Database for PostgreSQL v16.4 - Flexible Server.
